# Regex doesn't match antMatcher URL pattern

Tags: java, regex, spring-security

I am trying to ignore a url from authentication I've tried multiple different patterns but java doesn't seem to be able to recognize them. My configure looks like this:

```
  @Override
  public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    super.configure(web);
    web.ignoring().antMatchers(
            "/api/pies.*active=true");
  }
```

the string I want to match and have spring security ignore is something like this: 
http://"someEnv"/"somePath"/api/pies?active=true

however no matter what wildcard combo I try it doesn't match.
The match has to have ?active=true

Below is the method def:

```
    @GetMapping()
    public ResponseEntity<List<PieResponseDto>> getPies(@RequestParam(name = "active") Boolean active)
```

below is the class def:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/api/pies", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

Comment: this was it. I switched it to regexMatchers and it worked! Thank you~!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.regexMatchers` instead of `.antMatchers` and then try this regex:

```
^[a-zA-Z:\/.]*pies\?active=true$
```

There are plenty of online tools for regex expressions. You can try for example this one: [online regex tester](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: I've tried regex testers and matched the string such as your pattern but when I feed it to the antMatchers function it doesn't pick it up.

Comment: Ups, because it is not Regex as you wrote in the title :) It's AntPattern. Try this: `/**/*?active=true` or just `/**/*active=true`

Comment: Oh that's new insight! Those patterns aren't working but I think it's because of the controller that picking up the response. I'll do some research and update the question

Comment: Your original pattern works! You just need to use .regexMatchers instead of .antMatchers if you edit your answer I can mark it correct!