# Allow language parameter in URL (Spring Boot / Security)

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, internationalization

**Hello dear community,**

---

details about my goal:

- Use **internationalization** in a **Spring Boot** application together with **Spring Security's authentication mechanism**

  - [Using Baeldung's Guide to internationalization](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-internationalization)

---

the actual result:

- The internationalization works very well

---

then I added security:

```
http.authorizeRequests()

    // Restrict Endpoints
    .antMatchers("/login/**").hasAnyRole("admin", "member")

    // Allow Forms
    .antMatchers("/member/**").permitAll()

    // Allow Resources
    .antMatchers("/js/**").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()

    // Deny All
    .anyRequest().authenticated();
}
```

Due to `.anyRequest().authenticated()` a request on the root path like `/?lang=de` will trigger authentication.

---

what I tried:

http.authorizeRequests()

```
    // Restrict Endpoints
    .antMatchers("/login/**").hasAnyRole("admin", "member")

    // Allow Forms
    .antMatchers("/member/**").permitAll()

    // Allow Resources
    .antMatchers("/js/**").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()

    // Trick to allow Internationalization
    .antMatchers("/*").permitAll()

    // Deny All
    .anyRequest().authenticated();
}
```

I added `.antMatchers("/*").permitAll()` which works, but it allows to much resources on the root path. My goal is to only allow `/?lang=de` without authentication.

Is there any opportunity?

---

My resources I studied but not get confortable with:

- [antMatchers Spring Security pattern with changeable URL user ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27649649/antmatchers-spring-security-pattern-with-changeable-url-user-id)
- [Regex doesn't match antMatcher URL pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57119334/regex-doesnt-match-antmatcher-url-pattern)

---

**Kind regards

OtenMoten**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally it's working.

Above I told I was not confortable with the mentioned stackoverflow links, but yet it's working.

I've added:

`.regexMatchers("/.*lang=.*").permitAll()`

http.authorizeRequests()

```
// Restrict Endpoints
.antMatchers("/login/**").hasAnyRole("admin", "member")

// Allow Forms
.antMatchers("/member/**").permitAll()

// Allow Resources
.antMatchers("/js/**").permitAll()
.antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()

.regexMatchers("/.*lang=.*").permitAll()

// Deny All
.anyRequest().authenticated();
```

}